# IronPython - how to rename a folder name

Tags: ironpython

for example:
how to rename C:\Program Files\Music_Files to C:\Program Files\MusicFiles

Answer (score 7):

And if you want to do it the python way:

```
import os
os.rename("c:\\Program Files\\Music_Files", "c:\\Program Files\\MusicFiles")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the .Net libraries, since IronPython can access them?

System.IO.Directory should have a Move method that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
os.rename(old_filename, new_filename)
```

Or you can use the method from .net library

```
System.IO.File.Move(@old_filename, @new_filename);
```

Check out this tutorial of Ironpython for android https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gavin.gbook

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

os.rename("c://your_directory/old_folder_name","c://your_directory/new_folder_name")